# Proving $End_B(N)$ is Semisimple Algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, representation-theory

Let $B$ be a semisimple algebra, and $N$ be a finitely generated $B$-module.
I am trying to prove $End_B(N)$ is a semisimple algebra.

Updated: I changed my attempt based on user26857's and Qiaochu's helpful comments.

My attempt:
Since $N$ is finitely generated, $N$ is the homomorphic image of the free module $\underbrace{B\oplus\dots\oplus B}_{k\ \text{times}}$, and thus $N$ is a semisimple $B$-module.

Write $N=M_1\oplus\dots\oplus M_k$, where $M_i$ are simple modules. By Schur's Lemma, each $Hom_B(M_i,M_j)$ is a division algebra. Thus $End_B(N)$ is isomorphic to a matrix with entries in $Hom_B(M_i,M_j)$, denoted $M_k(D)$.

Thus by Wedderburn's Structure Theorem, $End_B(N)$ is a semisimple algebra.

Notation: $\{n_1,n_2,\dots,n_k\}$ is a generating set for $N$.

Is the above approach possible? Thanks.

If no, why not, and any other way to prove $End_B(N)$ is a semisimple algebra?

Comment: Write $N$ as a finite direct sum of simple modules, then use Schur's lemma.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Thanks for your hint. I corrected my answer based on your hint.

Comment: You don't need to appeal to Wedderburn here: this is the easy direction.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan How do I see easily that $M_k(D)$ is semisimple?

Comment: Decompose it as a module over itself; you'll get $k$ copies of the unique simple module, which is $D^k$.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Do you mean $k^2$ copies?

Comment: No, I mean $k$ copies.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Ah... Can you elaborate a bit on your previous comment (Decompose it as a module over itself...)? I don't quite understand it.